# JSON serialization of Google App Engine models

Tags: python, json, google-app-engine

I've been searching for quite a while with no success. My project isn't using Django, is there a simple way to serialize App Engine models (google.appengine.ext.db.Model) into JSON or do I need to write my own serializer?

**Model:**

```
class Photo(db.Model):
    filename = db.StringProperty()
    title = db.StringProperty()
    description = db.StringProperty(multiline=True)
    date_taken = db.DateTimeProperty()
    date_uploaded = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    album = db.ReferenceProperty(Album, collection_name='photo')
```

Answer (score 62, accepted):

A simple recursive function can be used to convert an entity (and any referents) to a nested dictionary that can be passed to `simplejson`:

```
import datetime
import time

SIMPLE_TYPES = (int, long, float, bool, dict, basestring, list)

def to_dict(model):
    output = {}

    for key, prop in model.properties().iteritems():
        value = getattr(model, key)

        if value is None or isinstance(value, SIMPLE_TYPES):
            output[key] = value
        elif isinstance(value, datetime.date):
            # Convert date/datetime to MILLISECONDS-since-epoch (JS "new Date()").
            ms = time.mktime(value.utctimetuple()) * 1000
            ms += getattr(value, 'microseconds', 0) / 1000
            output[key] = int(ms)
        elif isinstance(value, db.GeoPt):
            output[key] = {'lat': value.lat, 'lon': value.lon}
        elif isinstance(value, db.Model):
            output[key] = to_dict(value)
        else:
            raise ValueError('cannot encode ' + repr(prop))

    return output
```

Comment: There is a small mistake in the code:
Where you have "output[key] = to_dict(model)" it should be: "output[key] = to_dict(value)".

Besides that it's perfect.

Thanks!

Comment: This code will fail when it encounters a UserProperty. I worked around it with doing "output[key] = str(value)" in the final else, instead of raising an error.

Comment: Great stuff. Small improvement is to use iterkeys() instead since you don't use "prop" there.

Comment: I've not tried all the possible types (date, GeoPt, ...), but it seems the datastore has exactly this method, and it's been working for strings and integers for me so far: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/functions#to_dict So I'm not sure you need to reinvent the wheel to serialize to json: `json.dumps(db.to_dict(Photo))`

Comment: @gentimouton That method is a new addition. It certainly didn't exist in 2009

Comment: to_dict is not recursive, and will not process datetime fields correctly

Answer (score 61):

This is the simplest solution I found. It requires only 3 lines of code.

Simply add a method to your model to return a dictionary:

```
class DictModel(db.Model):
    def to_dict(self):
       return dict([(p, unicode(getattr(self, p))) for p in self.properties()])
```

SimpleJSON now works properly:

```
class Photo(DictModel):
   filename = db.StringProperty()
   title = db.StringProperty()
   description = db.StringProperty(multiline=True)
   date_taken = db.DateTimeProperty()
   date_uploaded = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
   album = db.ReferenceProperty(Album, collection_name='photo')

from django.utils import simplejson
from google.appengine.ext import webapp

class PhotoHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
   def get(self):
      photos = Photo.all()
      self.response.out.write(simplejson.dumps([p.to_dict() for p in photos]))
```

Comment: hey thanks for the tip. this works great except I can't seem to serialize the date field. I get:

TypeError: datetime.datetime(2010, 5, 1, 9, 25, 22, 891937) is not JSON serializable

Comment: Hi, thanks for pointing the issue.

The solution is to convert the date object to a string. For instance you can wrap the call to "getattr(self, p)" with "unicode()". I edited code to reflect this.

Comment: To remove db.Model's meta fields, use this: dict([(p, unicode(getattr(self, p))) for p in self.properties() if not p.startswith("_")])

Comment: for ndb, see fredva's answer.

Comment: self.properties() didn't work for me. I used self._properties.

Full line:

return dict([(p, unicode(getattr(self, p))) for p in self._properties])

Answer (score 15):

In the latest (1.5.2) release of the App Engine SDK, a `to_dict()` function that converts model instances to dictionaries was introduced in `db.py`.  See the [release notes](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/SdkReleaseNotes#Version_1.5.2_-_July_21,_2011).

There is no reference to this function in the documentation as of yet, but I have tried it myself and it works as expected.

Comment: I wonder if this has been removed? I get `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'to_dict'` when I `from google.appengine.ext import db` and use `simplejson.dumps(db.to_dict(r))` (where r is an instance of a db.Model subclass).
I don't see "to_dict" in google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/db/*

Comment: it has to be used like  "db.to_dict(ObjectOfClassModel)"

Comment: for a ndb object, self.to_dict() does the job.  If you want to make the class serializable by the standard json module, add 'def default(self, o): return o.to_dict()` to the class

Answer (score 7):

To serialize models, add a custom json encoder as in the following python:

```
import datetime
from google.appengine.api import users
from google.appengine.ext import db
from django.utils import simplejson

class jsonEncoder(simplejson.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, datetime.datetime):
            return obj.isoformat()

        elif isinstance(obj, db.Model):
            return dict((p, getattr(obj, p)) 
                        for p in obj.properties())

        elif isinstance(obj, users.User):
            return obj.email()

        else:
            return simplejson.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)


# use the encoder as: 
simplejson.dumps(model, cls=jsonEncoder)
```

This will encode:

- a date as as isoformat string ([per this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455580/json-datetime-between-python-and-javascript/456032#456032)),
- a model as a dict of its properties,
- a user as his email.

To decode the date you can use this javascript:

```
function decodeJsonDate(s){
  return new Date( s.slice(0,19).replace('T',' ') + ' GMT' );
} // Note that this function truncates milliseconds.
```

Note: Thanks to user [pydave](https://stackoverflow.com/users/79125/pydave) who edited this code to make it more readable. I had originally had used python's if/else expressions to express `jsonEncoder` in fewer lines as follows: (I've added some comments and used `google.appengine.ext.db.to_dict`, to make it clearer than the original.)

```
class jsonEncoder(simplejson.JSONEncoder):
  def default(self, obj):
    isa=lambda x: isinstance(obj, x) # isa(<type>)==True if obj is of type <type>
    return obj.isoformat() if isa(datetime.datetime) else \
           db.to_dict(obj) if isa(db.Model) else \
           obj.email()     if isa(users.User) else \
           simplejson.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to write your own "parser" (a parser would presumably turn JSON into a Python object), but you can still serialize your Python object yourself.

Using [simplejson](http://simplejson.googlecode.com/svn/tags/simplejson-2.0.9/docs/index.html):

```
import simplejson as json
serialized = json.dumps({
    'filename': self.filename,
    'title': self.title,
    'date_taken': date_taken.isoformat(),
    # etc.
})
```

Comment: Yes, but I don't want to have to do this for every model. I'm trying to find a scalable approach.

Comment: oh and i'm really surprised that I can't find any best practices on this. I thought app engine model + rpc + json was a given...

Answer (score 4):

For simple cases, I like the approach advocated [here](http://skonieczny.pl/blog/it-should-just-work/post/2009/04/30/json-serialization-of-google-app-engine-models/) at the end of the article:

```
  # after obtaining a list of entities in some way, e.g.:
  user = users.get_current_user().email().lower();
  col = models.Entity.gql('WHERE user=:1',user).fetch(300, 0)

  # ...you can make a json serialization of name/key pairs as follows:
  json = simplejson.dumps(col, default=lambda o: {o.name :str(o.key())})
```

The article also contains, at the other end of the spectrum, a complex serializer class that enriches django's (and does require `_meta` -- not sure why you're getting errors about _meta missing, perhaps the bug described [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-app-engine-django/issues/detail?id=52)) with the ability to serialize computed properties / methods.  Most of the time you serialization needs lay somewhere in between, and for those an introspective approach such as @David Wilson's may be preferable.

Answer (score 3):

Even if you are not using django as a framework, those libraries are still available for you to use.

```
from django.core import serializers
data = serializers.serialize("xml", Photo.objects.all())
```

Comment: Did you mean serializers.serialize("json", ...)? That throws "AttributeError: 'Photo' object has no attribute '_meta'". FYI - serializers.serialize("xml", Photo.objects.all()) throws "AttributeError: type object 'Photo' has no attribute 'objects'". serializers.serialize("xml", Photo.all()) throws "SerializationError: Non-model object (<class 'model.Photo'>) encountered during serialization".

Answer (score 2):

If you use [app-engine-patch](http://code.google.com/p/app-engine-patch/) it will automatically declare the `_meta` attribute for you, and then you can use `django.core.serializers` as you would normally do on django models (as in sledge's code).

App-engine-patch has some other cool features such has an hybrid authentication (django + google accounts), and the admin part of django works.

Comment: what's the difference between app-engine-patch vs google-app-engine-django vs the django version shipped with app engine python sdk?  From what I understand, app-engine-patch is more complete?

Comment: I haven't tried the version of django on app engine, but I think it's integrated as is. google-app-engine-django if I'm not mistaken tries to make django's model work with app-engine (with some limitations). app-engine-patch uses directly app-engine models, they just add some minore stuffs to it. There is a comparison between the two on their website.

Answer (score 2):

Mtgred's answer above worked wonderfully for me -- I slightly modified it so I could also get the key for the entry.  Not as few lines of code, but it gives me the unique key:

```
class DictModel(db.Model):
def to_dict(self):
    tempdict1 = dict([(p, unicode(getattr(self, p))) for p in self.properties()])
    tempdict2 = {'key':unicode(self.key())}
    tempdict1.update(tempdict2)
    return tempdict1
```

Answer (score 2):

I've extended the JSON Encoder class written by [dpatru](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3063649) to support:

- Query results properties (e.g. car.owner_set)
- ReferenceProperty - recursively turn it into JSON
- Filtering properties - only properties with a `verbose_name` will be encoded into JSON

  ```
  class DBModelJSONEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
      """Encodes a db.Model into JSON"""

      def default(self, obj):
          if (isinstance(obj, db.Query)):
              # It's a reference query (holding several model instances)
              return [self.default(item) for item in obj]

          elif (isinstance(obj, db.Model)):
              # Only properties with a verbose name will be displayed in the JSON output
              properties = obj.properties()
              filtered_properties = filter(lambda p: properties[p].verbose_name != None, properties)

              # Turn each property of the DB model into a JSON-serializeable entity
              json_dict = dict([(
                      p,
                      getattr(obj, p)
                          if (not isinstance(getattr(obj, p), db.Model))
                          else
                      self.default(getattr(obj, p)) # A referenced model property
                  ) for p in filtered_properties])

              json_dict['id'] = obj.key().id() # Add the model instance's ID (optional - delete this if you do not use it)

              return json_dict

          else:
              # Use original JSON encoding
              return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)
  ```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by https://stackoverflow.com/users/806432/fredva, the to_dict works great. Here is my code i'm using.

```
foos = query.fetch(10)
prepJson = []

for f in foos:
  prepJson.append(db.to_dict(f))

myJson = json.dumps(prepJson))
```

Comment: yes, and there is also a "to_dict" on Model...this function is the key to making this whole problem as trivial as it should be.  It even works for NDB with "structured" and "repeated" properties!

Answer (score 1):

There's a method, "Model.properties()", defined for all Model classes.  It returns the dict you seek.

```
from django.utils import simplejson
class Photo(db.Model):
  # ...

my_photo = Photo(...)
simplejson.dumps(my_photo.properties())
```

See [Model properties](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/modelclass.html#Model_properties) in the docs.

Comment: Some objects aren't "JSON serializable": `TypeError: <google.appengine.ext.db.StringProperty object at 0x4694550> is not JSON serializable`

Answer (score 1):

These APIs (google.appengine.ext.db) are no longer recommended. Apps that use these APIs can only run in the App Engine Python 2 runtime and will need to migrate to other APIs and services before migrating to the App Engine Python 3 runtime.
To know more: [click here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/refdocs/google.appengine.ext.db)

Answer (score 0):

To serialize a Datastore Model instance you can't use json.dumps (haven't tested but Lorenzo pointed it out). Maybe in the future the following will work.

http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html

```
import json
string = json.dumps(['foo', {'bar': ('baz', None, 1.0, 2)}])
object = json.loads(self.request.body)
```

Comment: the question is about converting an AppEngine Datastore Model instance to JSON. You solution is only about converting a Python dictionary to JSON

Comment: @tunedconsulting I haven't tried serializing a Datastore Model instance with json.dumps but assume it would work with any object. A bug report should be submitted if it isn't as the documentation states that json.dumps takes an object as parameter. It is added as a comment with only re comment that it didn't exist in 2009. Added this answer because it seems a bit out dated but if it would not work then I'm happy to remove it.

Comment: If you try to json.dumps an _entity_ object or a _model_ class you get TypeError: 'is not JSON serializable' <Object at 0x0xxxxxx>. GAE's Datastore has its own datatypes (for dates for example). The current right answer, tested and working, is the one from dmw that transforms some problematic datatypes into serializable ones.

Comment: @tunedconsulting Thank you for your input on this, I will update my answer.