# Excluding BlobProperty in GAE model in to_dict

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I learned some python for a project using GAE and I've got everything figured out except one thing.  When converting a GAE model to JSON, how do I skip over a BlobProperty (say, if a Profile model has an avatar property)?  So instead of the standard:

```
def to_dict(self):
    return dict([(p, unicode(getattr(self, p))) for p in self.properties()])
```

I'd need something like:

```
def to_dict(self):
    return dict([(p, unicode(getattr(self, p))) for p in self.properties() if type(p) is not db.BlobProperty])
```

But it's not working for me. I was looking at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10675849/converting-gae-model-into-json), which is pretty similar, but I can't get it to work for my case.  I'm probably doing something wrong in Python .  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

db.Model.properties() returns a dict of strings to properties, and dict.**iter** yields keys only.  So type(p) is always going to be a string.  If you want to keys and values use [db.Model.properties().items()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items) instead.  db.Model.

Instead try something like:

```
def to_dict(self):
  return dict([(p, unicode(getattr(self, p))) for p,t in self.properties().items() if type(t) is not db.BlobProperty])
```

Comment: Wow thanks, that did it.  I'd upvote, but it says I need more "reputation." Looks like I should spend some more time learning Python.  Know of any editors that are easy and free?  I'm using xcode for this iOS project but it doesn't help me at all with the debugging in Python.

Comment: Ran into another problem: one of the model properties is a list. How can I get the unicode characters out of it?  I need to use json.dumps probably, but where in the code?