# AppEngine Making ndb models json serializable

Tags: python, google-app-engine

We have an ndb model that we would like to make json serializable. The models are fairly simple along the lines of:

```
class Pasta(ndb.Model):
   name = ndb.StringProperty()
   type = ndb.StringProperty()
   comments = ndb.JsonProperty()
```

Then on the handler side we would like to do something along the lines of:

`json.dumps(Pasta.query(Pasta.name=="Ravioli").fetch())` and return it to the client, but it keeps throwing json parse errors since the class Pasta is not json serializable. So, the question is, do we have to implement `__str__` or `__repr__` or is there a niftier way to do it?

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531501/json-serialization-of-google-app-engine-models

Comment: Doggone it. Thank you. I can almost never find these questions when I search for them.

Comment: NP. It's for DB but should be no big deal to convert.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

`ndb.Model` instances have a `to_dict()` function:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/modelclass#Model_to_dict

the simplest way is:

```
json.dumps([p.to_dict() for p in Pasta.query(Pasta.name == "Ravioli").fetch()])
```

Comment: It's probably worth noting that the `to_dict` does not include the `key` in the model. So you may wish to do something like `json.dumps([dict(p.to_dict(), **dict(id=p.key.id())) for p in ...`

Comment: To avoid errors with datetime, use `json.dumps(..., default=str)`

Answer (score 10):

I don't believe it's documented, but for existing `ext.db` Models, you can use `db.to_dict()` (see [here](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.py#3947)).

Be careful though with `db.ReferenceProperty`'s and `db.DateTimeProperty`'s as they will throw errors when you call `json.dumps()`. The quick solution is a custom JSONEncoder:

```
from datetime import datetime, date, time
from google.appengine.ext import db

import json

class JSONEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):

    def default(self, o):
        # If this is a key, you might want to grab the actual model.
        if isinstance(o, db.Key):
            o = db.get(o)

        if isinstance(o, db.Model):
            return db.to_dict(o)
        elif isinstance(o, (datetime, date, time)):
            return str(o)  # Or whatever other date format you're OK with...
```

Then to encode with this:

```
JSONEncoder().encode(YourModel.all().fetch())
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can just add a computed property to the model like below:

```
class Taxes(ndb.Model):
    name = ndb.StringProperty()
    id = ndb.ComputedProperty(lambda self: self.key.id())
```

then in your get method just call to_dict and you will get the id

```
rows = [row.to_dict() for row in Taxes.query()]
self.response.write(json.dumps(rows))
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is a ndb.KeyProperty referring a different model, you could very well override dictionary method as shown below

```
def to_dict(self):
        result = super(Point, self).to_dict()
        result['x']=self.x.get().to_dict()
        result['y']=self.y.get().to_dict()
        return result
```

And if the ndb.KeyProperty is a list (with repeated set to True), use below method to fetch the referred model using get_multi

```
def to_dict(self):
       result = super(Figure, self).to_dict()
       result['points']=[p.to_dict() for p in ndb.get_multi(self.points)]
       return result
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is a ndb.KeyProperty referring a different model, you could very well override dictionary method as shown below

```
def to_dict(self):
        result = super(Point, self).to_dict()
        result['x']=self.x.get().to_dict()
        result['y']=self.y.get().to_dict()
        return result
```

And if the ndb.KeyProperty is a list (with repeated set to True), and if you intend to serialize the referred model as well, use below method to fetch the referred model using get_multi

```
def to_dict(self):
       result = super(Figure, self).to_dict()
       result['points']=[p.to_dict() for p in ndb.get_multi(self.points)]
       return result
```