# 'Post' object has no attribute 'properties'

Tags: django, python-2.7, app-engine-ndb, jsonserializer

I am using Django 1.11 and Python 2.7 with Google Appengine's NDB Library. I want to serialize my NDB model. I am following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2305601/9374364).

models.py

```
class DictModel(ndb.Model):
def to_dict(self):
   return dict([(p, unicode(getattr(self, p))) for p in self.properties()])

class Post(DictModel):
    text = ndb.StringProperty()
    date = ndb.DateProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    url = ndb.StringProperty()
    url_title = ndb.StringProperty()
    url_text = ndb.StringProperty()
    privacy = ndb.StringProperty()
    tags = ndb.StringProperty()

    @classmethod
    def query_post(cls, ancestor_key):
        return cls.query(ancestor=ancestor_key).order(-cls.date)
```

views.py

```
@login_required()  
def get_user_profile(request, username):
    user = User.objects.get(username=username)
    ancestor_key = ndb.Key(Post, username)
    posts = Post.query_post(ancestor_key)
    print(posts)
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps([p.to_dict() for p in posts]), content_type='application/json')
```

Comment: The answer you're using is not for ndb, but for the even older db library. ndb has a built-in `to_dict` method you can use.

Comment: By using the built in, I get an error datetime.date(2006, 11, 1) is not JSON serializable. How to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Try something along these lines:

```
def to_dict(self):
   return dict([(p, p.strftime('%y/%m/%d %H:%M:%s') if isinstance(p, datetime.datetime) else \
                    unicode(getattr(self, p))) for p in self._properties.itervalues()])
```

Note: you may need just `datetime` instead of `datetime.datetime`, depending on how you import it.

You can similarly expand it for other non-serializable property types you may encounter, if any.