# Serializing resultset returned from mysqldb in python

Tags: python, django, json, mysql

Can anyone please help me in serializing resultset returned using mysqldb in python?

I get typeerror: `datetime.date(2007, 11, 15) is not JSON serializable`

What is the best way to do serialize into Json object in python?

I am using json.dumps(resultset) to serialize resultset...

Answer (score 3):

Set the "default" function passed to json.dump:

```
>>> d=datetime.datetime.now()
>>> json.dumps(d,default=str)
'"2009-12-18 14:22:21.405095"'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [rfc3339](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3339.txt) strings instead:

```
  json.dump(datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'))
```

See: [JSON datetime between Python and JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455580/json-datetime-between-python-and-javascript)

Comment: I have corrected my question, I am passing resultset to json.dumps and not datetime...

Answer (score 0):

[Serializing Django objects (Django Docs)](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/)

[Serializing Python Objects (Dive Into Python 3)](http://diveintopython3.org/serializing.html)