# Returning extended fields in JSON

Tags: python, django, django-views, json

I have two tabels(Ingredient_Step and Ingredient) in on relation as you can see below:

Models.Py

```
class Ingredient_Step(models.Model):
    ingredient = models.ForeignKey(Ingredient)
    Step = models.ForeignKey(Step)        
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'{}'.format(self.Step)

class Ingredient(models.Model):
    IngredientName = models.CharField(max_length=200,unique=True)
    Picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='Ingredient')    
    def __unicode__(self):
         return u'{}'.format(self.IngredientName)
```

In a function, i need serialize a JSON object from a query that returns from "Ingredient_step", but I need send the field "IngredientName", who comes from "Ingredient" table.
I try using "ingredient__IngredientName" but it fails.

Views.Py:

```
def IngredientByStep(request):
    if request.is_ajax() and request.GET and 'id_Step' in request.GET:
        if request.GET["id_Step"] != '':
            IngStp = Ingredient_Step.objects.filter(Step =request.GET["id_Step"])
            return JSONResponse(serializers.serialize('json', IngStp, fields=('pk','ingredient__IngredientName')))
```

How i can call extends field from a relation?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This "feature" of Django (and many ORM's like SQLAlchemy) are called Lazy Loading, meaning data is only loaded from related models if you specifically ask for them. In this case, build your IngStp as a list of results, and make sure to access the property for each result before serializing.

Here's an example of how to do that: [Django: Include related models in JSON string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4039019/django-include-related-models-in-json-string)