# Django Queryset to dict for use in json

Tags: django

I have the following queryset:

```
prices = Price.objects.filter(product=product).values_list('price', 'valid_from')
```

How can i get the prices as "json"

```
{"aaData": [
    ["70.1700", "2007-01-01"], # price, valid_form
    ["72.6500", "2008-01-01"], # price, valid_form
    ["74.5500", "2009-01-01"], # price, valid_form
    ["76.6500", "2010-01-01"]
]}
```

Answer (score 43):

A better approach is to use [DjangoJSONEncoder](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/serializers/json.py). It has support for `Decimal`.

```
import json
from django.core.serializers.json import DjangoJSONEncoder

prices = Price.objects.filter(product=product).values_list('price', 'valid_from')

prices_json = json.dumps(list(prices), cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)
```

Very easy to use. No jumping through hoops for converting individual fields to `float`.

**Update** : Changed the answer to use builtin json instead of simplejson.

Comment: Just a note... the use of `django.utils.simplejson` has been depricated as of Django 1.5. See the [release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.5/#system-version-of-simplejson-no-longer-used) for more info.

Comment: following the example shown:
once I have `prices_json`  how do I pass it over to the template/js? and how do I access it from there?

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.utils import simplejson

prices = Price.objects.filter(product=product).values_list('price', 'valid_from')
simplejson.dumps({'aaData': prices})
```

**Edit**

It wasn't clear from your question that `price` is a `DecimalField`. It looks like you'd need to convert from `Decimal` to `float`:

```
simplejson.dumps({'aaData': (float(price), valid_from) for price, valid_from in prices})
```

Alternatively, if you want the price to be a string:

```
simplejson.dumps({'aaData': (str(price), valid_from) for price, valid_from in prices})
```

Comment: Error: Decimal('70.1700') is not JSON serializable