# Object of type QuerySet is not JSON serializable

Tags: django

I have these list objects that are callable by name. They have number values that users can input. how would I turn each of those lists to form that chart js can render? I tried with this: [Django Queryset to dict for use in json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10502135/django-queryset-to-dict-for-use-in-json) but could not get it working. Getting "Object of type QuerySet is not JSON serializable". Chart js would need to have own line for each of those list and show the values in those lines. This is how far I got with the link in **views**:

**First I get all of users lists:**

```
user_lists = List.objects.filter(user=user)
```

**Then I get number values for each list**

```
list_data = {}
for list in user_lists:
    list_data[list.name] = DataItem.objects.filter(list=list)
```

Here is where I get stuck when I should **convert these lists** to something that chart.js can understand..

```
list_data_json = json.dumps(list_data, cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)
```

btw am I in the right tracks to put this conversion to views, right? or does it belong somewhere else?

Dont know if these are needed but here are **models** for these lists and the data items in them:

```
class List(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="")
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='lists')

def __str__(self):
    return self.name

class Meta:
    unique_together = ['name', 'user']


class DataItem(models.Model):
    data = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    list = models.ForeignKey(List, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='data_items')
```

**EDIT**
output query set looks like this (this is what json.dumps is trying to read i quess):

```
<QuerySet [{'name': 'squat', 'data_items__data': 1}, {'name': 'deadlift', 'data_items__data': 55}, {'name': 'Chest', 'data_items__data': None}, {'name': 'asd', 'data_items__data': 444}, {'name': 'asd', 'data_items__data': 32342}, {'name': 'asd', 'data_items__data': 42342}]>
```

And for me that looks good, there is a list of lists and list has a name "squats" and then values. But getting this error again "'QuerySet' object is not callable"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know what fields you want to pass to chart.js, you can do a specific `values()` query to get a dictionary, which you can easily serialize with `json.dumps`, more or less like this:

```
user_lists = (List.objects
    .filter(user=user)
    .select_related('user')
    .prefetch_related('data_items')
    .values('user__username', 'data_items__data')  # all fields you need
)

list_data_json = json.dumps(list(user_lists))
```

Comment: Duh ! Should have thought of it (facepalm).

Comment: I got error "'List' object is not callable" @Endre Both

Comment: @JoonasMykkänen you must have used `list` as a variable name (probably instead of `user_lists`) which shadows the builtin `list` type.

Comment: The solution is [not far off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31087111/typeerror-list-object-is-not-callable-in-python)...

Comment: Edited post! @brunodesthuilliers

Comment: @JoonasMykkänen  "XXX object is not callable" errors means that you've shadowed a function or class name with another variable. If you name your queryset `list` (ie : `list = List.objects.filter(...)`) then try to call `list` (ie : json.dumps(list(something))`, then of course you get this kind of error since the name `list` doesn't refer to the builtin `list` type but to whatever you assigned to it. Note that this is basic Python stuff (ok, basic python gotcha if you come from a language where functions and classes are not objects).

Answer (score 1):

despite what one could expect, `DjangoJSONEncoder` doesn't handle querysets nor models instances ([see here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/2.1/topics/serialization/#djangojsonencoder) for the types `DjangoJSONEncoder` deals with) - this part is actually handled by the serializer itself, but a serializer expects a  `Queryset` and not a dict of querysets.

IOW, you will have to [write your own encoder](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.JSONEncoder.default) (based on `DjangoJSONEncoder`) to handle querysets and models (hint: `someobj.__dict__` returns the object's attributes as a dict, which you can filter out to remove irrelevant django stuff like `_state`)

Comment: I have zero knowledge on javascript, only using since need those charts.. Could it be done with each queryset separately with serializer? If possible how? @bruno desthuilliers

Comment: This has nothing to do with Javascript actually (json is NOT javascript, it's a text format based on js syntax). And you cannot jsonify querysets separately, put them in the dict and jsonify the whole dict, as querysets would be doubly encoded (so the result would not be valid json). The solution I describe - which is _really_ easy to setup actually) is the one correct solution.

Comment: or actually just use Endre Both's solution which is much simpler and smarter xD

Comment: well I'm new to jsons and stuff so I would not know :D