# Django is producing a useless JSON object from objects.all()

Tags: python, json, django, django-models, django-views

I've built a Django view for the sake of returning a pure JSON object:

```
from django.core import serializers
import json
def testjson(request):
    all_objects = list(Message.objects.all())

    to_json = serializers.serialize('json', all_objects)

    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(to_json), mimetype='application/json')
```

to_json above only ends up looking something like this:

```
\"employees\": [
{ \"firstName\":\"John\" , \"lastName\":\"Doe\" }, 
{ \"firstName\":\"Anna\" , \"lastName\":\"Smith\" }, 
{ \"firstName\":\"Peter\" , \"lastName\":\"Jones\" }
]
```

This is completely useless with the `\` and I can't figure out how to get rid of them. 
I've tried this but the `\` triggers an escape character:

```
to_json = to_json.replace('\', '')
```

How do I change the JSON object to replace the `\"` with just `"`?

Comment: Are you evaluating this in the interactive Python shell? If so, this could be an artifact of that, since the shell automatically escapes the hyphens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to call `json.dumps()`, `serialize()` would make a json string for your response:

```
from django.core import serializers

def testjson(request):
    data = serializers.serialize('json', Message.objects.all())
    return HttpResponse(data, mimetype='application/json')
```

Also see:

- [<Django object > is not JSON serializable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16790375/django-object-is-not-json-serializable)