# Django view code has weird behaviour

Tags: python, django

I wrote this Django view method:

```
def list_all_devices(request):

    all_devices_info = []
    fields = Devices.objects.all()
    for field in fields:
        device = Devices.objects.filter(device_id=field.device_id).values()
        dev = device[0]

        dev['variables'] = Variables.objects.filter(device_id=field.device_id).values()

        del dev['device_creation_datetime']
        all_devices_info.append(dev)

    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(all_devices_info), content_type="application/json")
```

For some reason the first code doesn't work, but if I do a minor modification like the following, it starts working, I can't figure out why.

```
def list_all_devices(request):

    all_devices_info = []
    fields = Devices.objects.all()
    for field in fields:
        device = Devices.objects.filter(device_id=field.device_id).values()
        dev = device[0]

        dev['variables'] = [v for v in Variables.objects.filter(device_id=field.device_id).values()]

        del dev['device_creation_datetime']
        all_devices_info.append(dev)

    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(all_devices_info), content_type="application/json")
```

When I analyze the modifications:

```
[v for v in Variables.objects.filter(device_id=field.device_id).values()]
```

and

```
Variables.objects.filter(device_id=field.device_id).values()
```

they seem similar, and both seem to be lists and have the same information inside. But when the `json.dumps` method is called over it, in the first code it throws the following error on the browser.

[image]

Comment: You're right: both the expressions give you a list, but both lists are very different.  As pointed in the answer below, the `[v for v ...]` gives you a *normal* Python list, whereas `Variable...values()` expression gives a Django querydict, which also is a list, but with some extra methods and attributes.

Comment: See this question: [<Django object > is not JSON serializable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16790375/django-object-is-not-json-serializable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Devices.objects.filter(device_id=field.device_id).values() is `ValuesQuerySet` which is derived from `QuerySet` and both of then are `unevaluated` which means that is a query yet is not executed on database until you apply list or iterate on it.
When you use `json.dumps` you need data not query.

Apply following to see the types:

```
Devices.objects.filter(device_id=field.device_id).values().__class__
```

> django.db.models.query.ValuesQuerySet

```
Devices.objects.filter(device_id=field.device_id).values().__class__.__base__
```

> django.db.models.query.QuerySet

Answer (score 1):

values() doesn't return a simple data type.

I tried with a django model:

```
dir(myModel.objects.all().values())
```

['**and**', '**bool**', '**class**', '**deepcopy**', '**delattr**', '**dict**', '**doc**', '**format**', '**getattribute**', '**getitem**', '**getstate**', '**hash**', '**init**', '**iter**', '**len**', '**module**', '**new**', '**nonzero**', '**or**', '**reduce**', '**reduce_ex**', '**repr**', '**setattr**', '**setstate**', '**sizeof**', '**str**', '**subclasshook**', '**weakref**', '_add_hints', '_as_sql', '_base_queryset_class', '_batched_insert', '_clone', '_create_object_from_params', '_db', '_earliest_or_latest', '_extract_model_params', '_fetch_all', '_fields', '_filter_or_exclude', '_for_write', '_has_filters', '_hints', '_insert', '_known_related_objects', '_merge_known_related_objects', '_merge_sanity_check', '_next_is_sticky', '_populate_pk_values', '_prefetch_done', '_prefetch_related_lookups', '_prefetch_related_objects', '_prepare', '_raw_delete', '_result_cache', '_setup_aggregate_query', '_setup_query', '_specialized_queryset_class', '_sticky_filter', '_update', 'aggregate', 'all', 'annotate', 'annotation_names', 'as_manager', 'bulk_create', 'complex_filter', 'count', 'create', 'dates', 'datetimes', 'db', 'defer', 'delete', 'distinct', 'earliest', 'exclude', 'exists', 'extra', 'extra_names', 'field_names', 'filter', 'first', 'get', 'get_or_create', 'in_bulk', 'is_compatible_query_object_type', 'iterator', 'last', 'latest', 'model', 'none', 'only', 'order_by', 'ordered', 'prefetch_related', 'query', 'raw', 'reverse', 'select_for_update', 'select_related', 'update', 'update_or_create', 'using', 'value_annotation', 'values', 'values_list']

And this is the dir for a python array:

```
dir([])
```

['**add**', '**class**', '**contains**', '**delattr**', '**delitem**', '**delslice**', '**doc**', '**eq**', '**format**', '**ge**', '**getattribute**', '**getitem**', '**getslice**', '**gt**', '**hash**', '**iadd**', '**imul**', '**init**', '**iter**', '**le**', '**len**', '**lt**', '**mul**', '**ne**', '**new**', '**reduce**', '**reduce_ex**', '**repr**', '**reversed**', '**rmul**', '**setattr**', '**setitem**', '**setslice**', '**sizeof**', '**str**', '**subclasshook**', 'append', 'count', 'extend', 'index', 'insert', 'pop', 'remove', 'reverse', 'sort']