# Django test client does not automatically serialize factories

Tags: python, django, django-models

Here's my code:

```
# models.py
class MyModel(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    ...

# views.py
def get_all_models(request):
    return JsonResponse({"models": list(MyModel.objects.all())})

# urls.py
path('/mypath', views.get_all_models, name='get_all_models'),
```

This code works just fine if I visit `/mypath`. However, when I run an automated test using Django's test client, I get this error:

```
*** TypeError: Object of type MyModel is not JSON serializable
```

this is my test:
from django.test import TestCase, Client
from blog.tests.factories.user import UserFactory
from blog.tests.factories.post import PostFactory

```
class MyModelTest(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.user = UserFactory.create()
        self.post = MyModelFactory.create(user=self.user)
        self.client = Client()

    def test_get_all_models(self):
        response = self.client.get("/mypath")
        pass
```

I suspect it has something to do with my factories:

```
import factory
from .models import User, MyModel

class UserFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = User

    username = factory.Faker('word')
    email = factory.Faker('email')

class MyModelFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel

    user = factory.SubFactory(UserFactory)
    name = factory.Faker('name')
```

How can I make my factories serializable?

**NOTE:**
This question is not a duplicate. The other questions linked have view handlers that return `HttpResponse` objects, instead of `JsonResponse` objects. This distinction is key to my problem, because the error I'm seeing is related to JSON serialization that is supposed to be addressed by the `JsonResponse` class.

Also, the other questions do not involve factories. Factories are another key component of what I'm trying to do, which is run integration tests against data generated by factories.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [<Django object > is not JSON serializable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16790375/django-object-is-not-json-serializable)

Comment: Not a duplicate. The person who asked that question was returning an HttpResponse, whereas I'm using a JsonResponse. Also that question does not involve factory boy.

Comment: Are you sure that when you go to `/mypath` in the browser works? Has data the development database?

Comment: It does, and the factories are also working as expected

Comment: Does the MyModel class have additional attributes or methods? If so, please update question to include full content of the class.

Answer (score 1):

The code you shared assumes `JSONResponse` will serialize an ORM object, but according to Django documentation, it won't:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/serialization/#djangojsonencoder

It will work if you serialize the Django ORM object before passing it to `JSONResponse`

Consider doing the following:

```
from django.core import serializers
data = serializers.serialize("json", MyModel.objects.all())
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/serialization/

django-rest-framework is a very popular lib used in scenarios like the one you shared
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/serialization/#djangojsonencoder

Answer (score 0):

what about this:

```
def get_all_models(request):
    return JsonResponse({"models": list(MyModel.objects.all().values())},safe=False)
```

the point is here:

```
MyModel.objects.all().values()
safe=False
```

Comment: @dopatraman I updated my answer, just add safe=False to JsonResponse

Comment: I appreciate the response, but even adding `safe=False` does not stop the error from throwing