# How to properly return Json reponse to template for ajax/jquery?

Tags: django, ajax, django-views

Here I am trying to search with the help of ajax and jquery with my django view. When I try to search like this by returning the `JsonReponse` instead of html_template it doesn't return data below the corresponding `id` in html

But When I return html from django view and create the new html for this searching results and including this template in the original template works perfectly but I find this a longer process So I tried to return json reponse from view and use that json objects in the template like this but it is not working.

How can I solve this ? I think I need to work on the ajax part .

```
def search_users(request):
    q = request.GET.get('q')
    if q:
        users = get_user_model().objects.filter(is_active=True).filter(profile__full_name__icontains=q)
        data = {'users': users}

    else:
        users = get_user_model().objects.filter(is_active=True)
        data = {'users':users}
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

ajax

```
$(function() {
    $('#search_users').keyup(function() {

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "{% url 'dashboard:search_users' %}",
            data: {
                'q' : $('#search_users').val(),

            },
            success: searchSuccess,
            dataType: 'json'
        });
    });
  });


function searchSuccess(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
{
    $('#search_users_results').json(data) #doing html instead of json works after returning html from django view 
}
```

In the terminal

```
TypeError: Object of type QuerySet is not JSON serializable
[15/Mar/2020 14:02:53] "GET /admin/dashboard/search/users/?q=tyj HTTP/1.1" 500 22660
```

Comment: Are you getting any exception on the server-side or client-side on making `ajax` call?

Comment: @Ejaz updated on question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [<Django object > is not JSON serializable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16790375/django-object-is-not-json-serializable)

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava Yes I did `list(users` and this error gone but the search results are not appearing in my html ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to extract values out of the query before sending it across instead of sending the model instance as it can't be serialized, is what the exception is saying.

So, you can just append `.values()` in the end and put in the list as below -

```
data = {'users': list(users.values())}
```

You may refer to it [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values).