# Can't Parse Client Side JSON Object Created with Python/Django

Tags: javascript, python, json, django, ajax

I'm passing an object of data from a Python/Django App to the front end using AJAX in JSON form. Everything is working correctly, except that I cannot parse the JSON object once in Javascript. I keep getting undefined. I've tried every approach I could think of and I am super stuck so I wanted to see if someone might be able to point out what I hope is a super simple oversight!

Snippet of Python/Django:

```
data = serializers.serialize('json', products)


  response = {'product_data': data,
              'product_count': product_count}
  return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response), content_type='application/json')
```

Snippet of AJAX Callback:

```
.done(function(data){

  console.log(data.product_count)
  console.log(data.product_data)
  console.log(data.product_data["model"])
  console.log(data.product_data[0])
  console.log(data.product_data[0]["model"])

})
```

Console Logs Response Snippet:

```
>1
>[{"model": "seller.product", "pk": 11048, "fields": {"seller": 132, "width": 211, "height": 3, "length": 350, "weight": 18600, "price": 11077, "color_id": null, "po_number": null, "po_sub_number": null, "custom_order_id": null, "active_at": "2019-08-02T01:27:23.410Z", "deactive_at": null, "in_holding": false, "approved_at": "2019-08-04T15:34:08.318Z", "sold_at": "2020-02-07T20:07:54.675Z", "slug": "colored-beni-ourain-rug", "created_at": "2019-08-02T01:23:51.650Z", "updated_at": "2020-02-07T20:07:54.675Z", "assets": [3567, 3581, 3585, 3572, 3573, 3574, 3577, 3582, 3583, 3584, 3586, 3587, 3589, 3594, 3596], "colors": [1, 2, 3, 4, 12], "shipping_options": [1]}}]
> undefined
> [
> undefined
```

The first console log of 1 is correct and in the second line the data I want is all there. But any time I try and get info out of it I just get undefined or a ] and I cannot figure it out. Can anyone help? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use JSONResponse instead of HttpResponse.
That way you don't need to handle anything in between.

```
return JSONResponse(products)
```

:)

"json.dumps" would've been sufficient tho, no need for another call to the serializer.

Comment: JsonReponse alone did not work. But added serializer with JsonResponse did. All working now. Thank you!

Comment: happy it worked. tho, all, json.dump, serializer and jsonresponse use serialization for objects. so, idk what actually changed for you there :D it seems like you have an object that cant be serialized by the standard serializer and is converted twice. without the actual model its hard to guess what is happening. :)

Comment: hey muzzletov, thought you (or anyone else) might want to know, the issue in the model was that there was a QuerySet in the model. I was able to develop a better solution with the use of the following post, which I think was a better question than mine: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16790375/django-object-is-not-json-serializable

Answer (score 1):

You're serializing you data multiple times, just put `products` into `response` without serializing it.

```
  response = {'product_data': products,
              'product_count': product_count}
  return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response), content_type='application/json')
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That's how I had it originally but got the following traceback:      
TypeError: Object of type ProductQuerySet is not JSON serializable

Comment: That's interesting, `ProductQuerySet is not JSON serializable` but `serializers.serialize` can serialize it...

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to `JSON.parse(data.product_data)` first.

Comment: Unfortunately, no luck. Parsing is just returning blank arrays.