# How to store objects of custom class as session variables in django?

Tags: python-3.x, django, web

In my case i wants to store object of my USER class to be stored as session variable
To be more precise my class contains several methods for USER
structure of my USER class

```
class USER:
    def __init__(self , phone_number_of_user = None , user_name  = None):
        self.phone_number = phone_number_of_user
        self.user_name    = user_name
    def login(self):
        login_code_will_be_here
    def get_user_name(self):
        return self.user_name
    def set_data_of_user_in_firebase(self , data = None):
        code to set data of user will be here
```

firstly i create a USER object

```
user = USER(phone_number = 9******** , user_name = John)
```

But when i tries to store my objects in session of django like this

```
request.session['user'] = user
```

django shows me following error

```
Object of type USER is not JSON serializable
```

Comment: you will have to serialize user object to JSON yourself 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16790375/django-object-is-not-json-serializable