# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token & : jquery django context dict error

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, json, django

I am trying to assign a `context` dict to a jQuery variable in my django `html` template and I am getting the following error message in my browser's console:

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token &`

This is how I've assigned the context value (dict) to the javascript variable:

```
var foo = {{ bar }};
```

Where `bar` is the context variable passed from the `view`

The context is not taken as a javascript object.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: post the view too, and do post the full stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

You can get variable as a string. like below,

```
var foo = '{{ bar }}';
```

then you can cast it to the appropriate type.
following code will help you to create a json variable using string.

```
var foo = (("{{ bar |safe}}").replace(/&(l|g|quo)t;/g, function(a,b){
        return {
            l   : '<',
            g   : '>',
            quo : '"'
        }[b];
    }));

foo = foo.replace(/u'/g, '\'')
foo = foo.replace(/'/g, '\"')

var myData = JSON.parse( foo )
```

Code taken from : 
[Passing objects from Django to Javascript DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7165656/passing-objects-from-django-to-javascript-dom#)