# Cannot serialize datetime as JSON from Cherrypy

Tags: python, json, datetime, cherrypy

I'm attempting to send a list of records in response to an Ajax query.  This works well unless the results include a datetime field when my process fails with the error `datetime.date(2011, 11, 1) is not JSON serializable`.

I attempted to combine the answer I found to a very [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455580/json-datetime-between-python-and-javascript) here with instructions in the [CherryPy documentation](http://docs.cherrypy.org/dev/refman/lib/jsontools.html) to use a custom json_out encoder, but it's not clear to me what signature that function must have.  The function I wrote is:

```
 def json_encoder(thing):

      if hasattr(thing, 'isoformat'):
           return thing.isoformat()
      else:
           return str(thing)
```

and now *any* use of json_out (even with no datetime in the output) gives me the error `TypeError: json_encoder() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)`.  But if the encoder doesn't take an argument, how does it receive the object to encode?

(Also, I assume my use of `str(thing)` as the default method of encoding is wrong and that this should be done with a call to whatever the default handler for json encoding is, but I'm not sure how to call that method).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I do the next in a similar case:

```
class DecimalEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, Decimal):
            return float(obj)
        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)
```

and at the call:

```
json.dumps(my_variable, cls=DecimalEncoder)
```

So in your case it should be like:

```
class DateEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if hasattr(obj, 'isoformat'):
            return obj.isoformat()
        else:
            return str(obj)
        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)


json.dumps(my_variable, cls=DateEncoder)
```

Comment: Thanks, I have rewritten my encoder as a class by copying yours.  However, I'm not calling json.dumps() but rather using CherryPy's json tools.  Those tools can be configured with a custom handler for encoding, but they want a function, not a class or an instance.

Comment: I have now removed the CherryPy tool for JSON encoding and am calling simplejson.dumps() directly.  With this configuration, the encoder as you showed me works correctly.  Thank you!

Comment: Is this v3 specific ?? I could not get it to work on v2.7.5 . The steps i followed were the same. This does not work if i want to jsonify the list of my models (say A), where an attribute of A is datetime type. I believe where we want to retrieve only one model's JSON this wll work fine

Comment: How does the `DateEncoder::default()` function ever call the last `return` statement?

Answer (score 12):

I got the same problem (Python 3.2, Cherrypy 3.2.2) and I solved it with the following code:

```
import cherrypy
import json
import datetime
class _JSONEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, datetime.date):
            return obj.isoformat()
        return super().default(obj)
    def iterencode(self, value):
        # Adapted from cherrypy/_cpcompat.py
        for chunk in super().iterencode(value):
            yield chunk.encode("utf-8")

json_encoder = _JSONEncoder()

def json_handler(*args, **kwargs):
    # Adapted from cherrypy/lib/jsontools.py
    value = cherrypy.serving.request._json_inner_handler(*args, **kwargs)
    return json_encoder.iterencode(value)
```

And then you can use the Cherrypy `json_out` decorator:

```
class Root:
     @cherrypy.expose
     @cherrypy.tools.json_out(handler=json_handler)
     def default(self, *args, **kwargs):
         ...
```

Comment: This better answers the OP's question.

Comment: The encoder is very good! I just wrote [an answer to improve the usage of it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34115215/1338062) :)

Answer (score 2):

For custom `json_handler` implementation, see Pierre's excellent answer. However, specifying `@cherrypy.tools.json_out(handler=json_handler)` every time you use the tool is a bit cumbersome, so as the [jsontools.json_out source code points out](https://github.com/cherrypy/cherrypy/blob/802d379ec3639354b96853716434e3b91207712e/cherrypy/lib/jsontools.py#L74-L76), it's better to use this:

```
cherrypy.config['tools.json_out.handler'] = json_handler
```

Also, you can enable tools on class level using [`_cp_config`](https://cherrypy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/config.html#cp-config-attaching-config-to-handlers):

```
class Example
_cp_config = {
  'tools.json_out.on': True
}
```