# serializing datetime with flasks tojson filter

Tags: python, serialization, mongodb, flask, jinja2

I'm getting this error:

```
TypeError: datetime.datetime(2012, 2, 12, 0, 47, 6, 542000) is not JSON serializable
```

when jinja is trying to parse this line:

```
var root_node_info = eval({{ nd|tojson|safe }});
```

nd contains a bson object from my mongo database. One of the fields is a datetime object. How can I get flask to serialize this properly?

This is my mongokit model(in case its relevant)

```
class Item(Document):
    structure = {
        "tldr": unicode,
        "body": unicode,
        "user": unicode,
        "time_submitted": datetime.datetime,
        "upvotes": int,
        "downvotes": int,
        "tags": [unicode]
    }

    validators = {
    }

    indexes = [
        {'fields':['user']},
        {'fields':['tags']}
    ]

    use_dot_notation = True

    required_fields = ['body', 'user', 'time_submitted']
    default_values = {'time_submitted': datetime.datetime.utcnow}

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<item %r>' % (self._id)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JSON does not handle `datetime` objects. Standard practice is to encode them as strings in ISO format. This [SO question about JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8011081/cannot-serialize-datetime-as-json-from-cherrypy) provides examples. You will need to [register](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/templating/?highlight=tojson#registering-filters) the new JSON encoder filter yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Just to be noted.

As of v0.10 Flask has the ability to specify your own [`json_encoder`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Flask.json_encoder).

And Flask’s default [`JSONEncoder`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.json.JSONEncoder) is aware of dates (and few other additional things).