# json with django and datetime

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I need to show a json of the model:

```
product = list(product.objects.all().values('title', 'date'))
return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(product))
```

My problem it's with date. The error message is: datetime.datetime(...., tzinfo=) is not JSON serializable

i need to show like:

```
[
    {
        title  : 'product 1',
        date  : '2013-06-01'
    },
    {
        title  : 'product 2',
        date : '2013-06-05',
    }
]
```

Some suggestions ?
And, How can i define the orders of fields in the json. ej: (title, date) or (date, title)

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does json serialization of datetime objects in python not work out of the box for datetime objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10721409/why-does-json-serialization-of-datetime-objects-in-python-not-work-out-of-the-bo)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use django serializer:

```
from django.core.serializers.json import DjangoJSONEncoder
simplejson.dumps(product, cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)
```

About defining order. Why would you need it? Dictionary is unordered collection. You could use list instead.

Comment: thank you. about order it's only to know. Can i define with simplejson the format date ?

Comment: I guess you are thinking wrong way. You shouldnt change format in JSON, its business of Javascript or whatever language you will use to receive json, to decode json and then format it in way you need.