# Unable to serialize datetime.datetime object in dictionary to JSON using python and trac

Tags: json, python-2.7, trac

I have a list of dictionaries (each dictionary representing 1 record of an SQL query) which I am trying to serialize as JSON. There are several datetime.date and datetime.datetime objects in these dictionaries which are proving difficult to serialize. Initially, the error message is:

```
TypeError: datetime.date(2012, 5, 23) is not JSON serializable
```

After adding a handler to the json.dumps call the error message is:

```
TypeError: date_handler() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

date_handler looks like this:

```
    def date_handler(obj):
        return obj.isoformat() if hasattr(obj, 'isoformat') else obj
```

I'm running this as part of a Trac plugin however I think this is just an isolated python issue but have no idea what to do to sort it - does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/455580 could provide some more insight/options, at least for preliminary solutions. There are critical comments related to timezone support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by applying `.isoformat()` fields that were dates or timestamps in the dictionary as I'm importing the data from a database and so know what the field types are beforehand, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

See a [solution from the Django](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1435/) domain.