# Get Python JSON to serialize datetime

Tags: python, datetime, python-2.7, json

Have some nested objects that I'd like serialize using JSON. The problem is that some of the properties contain `datetime`s. When I try to serialize these pbjects, Python throws an exception:

```
TypeError: datetime.datetime(2012, 6, 5, 17, 49, 35, 672115) is not JSON serializable
```

Using Python 2.7, is there a way to tell the json serializer: "When you see a datetime, don't be annoying and throw an exception, just serialize using: `property.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %I:%M%p')`"

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python JSON encoder to support datetime?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12122007/python-json-encoder-to-support-datetime)

Comment: possible duplicate of [JSON datetime between Python and JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/455580/json-datetime-between-python-and-javascript)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll want to define a helper function that will serialize `datetime` objects, and use `default` kwarg of [json.dump](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html#json.dump) or json.dumps. See the comments with links to the duplicate answers.

Also, you will want to consider whether to support or not to support timezone-aware `datetime` objects. And whether you want to preserve the timezone during the serialization or just convert to UTC prior to serialization.

Here's an example that assumes you want to convert to UTC before serialization. It relies upon [python-dateutil](http://labix.org/python-dateutil) library:

```
from dateutil.tz import tzutc

UTC = tzutc()

def serialize_date(dt):
    """
    Serialize a date/time value into an ISO8601 text representation
    adjusted (if needed) to UTC timezone.

    For instance:
    >>> serialize_date(datetime(2012, 4, 10, 22, 38, 20, 604391))
    '2012-04-10T22:38:20.604391Z'
    """
    if dt.tzinfo:
        dt = dt.astimezone(UTC).replace(tzinfo=None)
    return dt.isoformat() + 'Z'
```