# Make the Python json encoder support Python's new dataclasses

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

Starting with Python 3.7, there is something called a dataclass:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Foo:
    x: str
```

However, the following fails:

```
>>> import json
>>> foo = Foo(x="bar")
>>> json.dumps(foo)
TypeError: Object of type Foo is not JSON serializable
```

How can I make `json.dumps()` encode instances of `Foo` into json [*objects*](https://www.json.org/)?

Comment: I'd be curious to know how to do the reverse if anyone knows i.e. what about the reverse? what if I have the data as a json file and want to load it back to my data class object?

Comment: @CharlieParker, if it's a simple dataclass with primitive types, I supposed you could do `json_file_as_dict = json.load(path_to_json_file)` and then `Foo(**json_file_as_dict)`.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3768895

Answer (score 226, accepted):

Much like you can add support to the JSON encoder for [`datetime` objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12122007/python-json-encoder-to-support-datetime) or Decimals, you can also provide a custom encoder subclass to serialize dataclasses:

```
import dataclasses, json

class EnhancedJSONEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
        def default(self, o):
            if dataclasses.is_dataclass(o):
                return dataclasses.asdict(o)
            return super().default(o)

json.dumps(foo, cls=EnhancedJSONEncoder)
```

Comment: It is important to  note, that for a dataclass called `Foo` and an instance `foo_instance = Foo(...)` both `dataclasses.is_dataclass(Foo)` and `dataclasses.is_dataclass(foo_instance)` evaluate to `True` leading to a `TypeError` for `dataclasses.asdict(o)` if `o` ist the dataclass itself and not an instance of it.

Comment: How about nesting - e.g.  serializing  `d={ 'a': Foo(1,2), 'b': Foo(3,4)}`

Comment: How do you handle object of type ndarray with this?

Comment: Using an json encoder like this will handle nesting just fine - the json serializer will use it to transform the sub-elements recursively.

Comment: As for handling ndarray, something like `if isinstance(obj, np.ndarray) and obj.ndim == 1: return obj.tolist()` will do the trick.  Though keep in mind that while python will happily serialize things like `NaN` or `Infinity`, that isn't legal according the the json spec and many decoders will reject it, so handling those in your encoder is possibly advisable.

Comment: whats wrong with `dataclasses.asdict()`?

Comment: also, what about the reverse? what if I have the data as a json file and want to load it back to my data class object?

Comment: curious, why did you choose dumps vs dumps?

Comment: I really, really wish the Python JSON serialiser looked for an `asdict()` method and used it if it's there.

Answer (score 113):

Can't you just use the `dataclasses.asdict()` function to convert the dataclass
to a dict? Something like:

```
>>> @dataclass
... class Foo:
...     a: int
...     b: int
...     
>>> x = Foo(1,2)
>>> json.dumps(dataclasses.asdict(x))
'{"a": 1, "b": 2}'
```

Comment: The dataclass may be deeply nested part of a large structure. By using a custom encoder, you can do `json.dumps({"obj": [something_that_may_or_may_not_contain_a_dataclass]})` as

Comment: asdict() will correctly process all nested data classes, as a result, we get nested dictionaries that normally load in jison's string (but! e.g., datetime type must be processed additionally, before loading into a string)

Comment: what about the reverse? what if I have the data as a json file and want to load it back to my data class object?

Comment: curious, why did you choose dumps vs dumps?

Comment: Or, perhaps `json.dumps(x, default=vars)` could work? Ah, wait, here's from the [`asdict()` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.asdict): *"... dataclasses, dicts, lists, and tuples are recursed into. Other objects are copied with copy.deepcopy()."*

Answer (score 79):

## Ways of getting JSONified dataclass instance

There are couple of options to accomplish that goal, selection of each imply analyze on which approach suits best for your needs:

#### [Standard library: dataclass.asdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html)

```
import dataclasses
import json


@dataclass.dataclass
class Foo:
    x: str

foo = Foo(x='1')
json_foo = json.dumps(dataclasses.asdict(foo)) # '{"x": "1"}'
```

Picking it back to dataclass instance isn't trivial, so you may want to visit that answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/53498623/2067976

#### [Marshmallow Dataclass](https://pypi.org/project/marshmallow-dataclass/)

```
from dataclasses import field
from marshmallow_dataclass import dataclass


@dataclass
class Foo:
    x: int = field(metadata={"required": True})

foo = Foo(x='1') # Foo(x='1')
json_foo = foo.Schema().dumps(foo) # '{"x": "1"}'

# Back to class instance.
Foo.Schema().loads(json_foo) # Foo(x=1)
```

As a bonus for `marshmallow_dataclass` you may use validation on the field itself, that validation will be used when someone deserialize the object from json using that schema.

#### [Dataclasses Json](https://pypi.org/project/dataclasses-json/)

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from dataclasses_json import dataclass_json


@dataclass_json
@dataclass
class Foo:
    x: int

foo = Foo(x='1')
json_foo = foo.to_json() # Foo(x='1')
# Back to class instance
Foo.from_json(json_foo) # Foo(x='1')
```

Also, in addition to that notice that marshmallow dataclass did type conversion for you whereas dataclassses-json(ver.: 0.5.1) ignores that.

#### [Write Custom Encoder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51286749/2067976)

Follow accepted miracle2k answer and reuse custom json encoder.

Comment: Thank you for `marshmallow_dataclass` it is really a good way to get a real object from JSON with validation (and even YAML).

Comment: @mickours you welcome :) btw I haven't mentioned that it will also works on python36 ( has dataclass backport under the hood)

Comment: coming for years of c# + Newtonsoft, dataclasses_json was the most "natural" - thanks!

Comment: If you are interested I would also take a look at `dataclass-wizard`. Its very similar to `dataclasses-json` and slightly more efficient. It also performs type conversions in most basic cases. Disclaimer: I am the creator of this library.

Answer (score 15):

If you are ok with using a library for that, you can use [dataclasses-json](https://github.com/lidatong/dataclasses-json). Here is an example:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

from dataclasses_json import dataclass_json


@dataclass_json
@dataclass
class Foo:
    x: str


foo = Foo(x="some-string")
foo_json = foo.to_json()
```

It also supports **embedded dataclasses** - if your dataclass has a field typed as another dataclass - if all dataclasses envolved have the `@dataclass_json` decorator.

Comment: I tried this with embedded dataclass and it dioes not work

Answer (score 14):

You can also implement the `asdict` and `json.dumps` method  within the class. In this case it wouldn't be necessary to import `json.dumps` into other parts of your project:

```py
from typing import List
from dataclasses import dataclass, asdict, field
from json import dumps


@dataclass
class TestDataClass:
    """
    Data Class for TestDataClass
    """
    id: int
    name: str
    tested: bool = False
    test_list: List[str] = field(default_factory=list)

    @property
    def __dict__(self):
        """
        get a python dictionary
        """
        return asdict(self)

    @property
    def json(self):
        """
        get the json formated string
        """
        return dumps(self.__dict__)


test_object_1 = TestDataClass(id=1, name="Hi")
print(test_object_1.__dict__)
print(test_object_1.json)
```

Output:

```
{'id': 1, 'name': 'Hi', 'tested': False, 'test_list': []}
{"id": 1, "name": "Hi", "tested": false, "test_list": []}
```

You can also create a parent class to inherit the methods:

```py
from typing import List
from dataclasses import dataclass, asdict, field
from json import dumps


@dataclass
class SuperTestDataClass:

    @property
    def __dict__(self):
        """
        get a python dictionary
        """
        return asdict(self)

    @property
    def json(self):
        """
        get the json formated string
        """
        return dumps(self.__dict__)


@dataclass
class TestDataClass(SuperTestDataClass):
    """
    Data Class for TestDataClass
    """
    id: int
    name: str
    tested: bool = False
    test_list: List[str] = field(default_factory=list)


test_object_1 = TestDataClass(id=1, name="Hi")
print(test_object_1.__dict__)
print(test_object_1.json)
```

Answer (score 13):

The simplest way to encode `dataclass` and `SimpleNamespace` objects is to provide the default function to `json.dumps()` that gets called for objects that can't be otherwise serialized, and return the object `__dict__`:

```py
json.dumps(foo, default=lambda o: o.__dict__)
```

Comment: This is a good idea, and should work in general for serializing *nested models* with simple types. The only cases which I guess this wouldn't support, would be complex Python types like Enum or datetime, or edge cases where you'd have a dataclass within a Union type, like `A | B`. This approach should nevertheless work for a simple case in general, as outlined in the original question.

Answer (score 11):

I'd suggest creating a parent class for your dataclasses with a `to_json()` method:

```py
import json
from dataclasses import dataclass, asdict

@dataclass
class Dataclass:
    def to_json(self) -> str:
        return json.dumps(asdict(self))

@dataclass
class YourDataclass(Dataclass):
    a: int
    b: int

x = YourDataclass(a=1, b=2)
x.to_json()  # '{"a": 1, "b": 2}'
```

This is especially useful if you have other functionality to add to all your dataclasses.

Answer (score 4):

## pydantic

With [pydantic](https://docs.pydantic.dev/) models you get a dataclasses-like experience and full support for dict and Json conversions (and much more).

Python 3.9 and above:

```py
from typing import Optional
from pydantic import BaseModel, parse_obj_as, parse_raw_as


class Foo(BaseModel):
    count: int
    size: Optional[float] = None


f1 = Foo(count=10)

# Parse to dict
print(f1.dict())
# OUT: {'count': 10, 'size': None}

# Load from dict
f2 = Foo.parse_obj({"count": 20})

# Parse to json
print(f2.json())
# OUT: {"count": 20, "size": null}
```

More options:

```py
# Load from json string
f3 = Foo.parse_raw('{"count": 30}')

# Load from json file
f4 = Foo.parse_file("path/to/data.json")

# Load from list of dicts
f_list1 = parse_obj_as(list[Foo], [{"count": 110}, {"count": 120}])
print(f_list1)
# OUT: [Foo(count=110, size=None), Foo(count=120, size=None)]

# Load from list in json string
f_list2 = parse_raw_as(list[Foo], '[{"count": 130}, {"count": 140}]')
print(f_list2)
# OUT: [Foo(count=130, size=None), Foo(count=140, size=None)]
```

Complex hierarchical data structures

```py
class Bar(BaseModel):
    apple = "x"
    banana = "y"


class Spam(BaseModel):
    foo: Foo
    bars: list[Bar]


m = Spam(foo={"count": 4}, bars=[{"apple": "x1"}, {"apple": "x2"}])
print(m)
# OUT: foo=Foo(count=4, size=None) bars=[Bar(apple='x1', banana='y'), Bar(apple='x2', banana='y')]

print(m.dict())
# OUT:
# {
#     'foo': {'count': 4, 'size': None},
#     'bars': [
#         {'apple': 'x1', 'banana': 'y'},
#         {'apple': 'x2', 'banana': 'y'},
#     ],
# }
```

Pydantic supports many standard types (like `datetime`) and special [commonly used types](https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/types/#pydantic-types) (like `EmailStr` and `HttpUrl`):

```py
from datetime import datetime
from pydantic import HttpUrl


class User(BaseModel):
    name = "John Doe"
    signup_ts: datetime = None
    url: HttpUrl = None


u1 = User(signup_ts="2017-07-14 00:00:00")
print(u1)
# OUT: signup_ts=datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 14, 0, 0) url=None name='John Doe'

u2 = User(url="http://example.com")
print(u2)
# OUT: signup_ts=None url=HttpUrl('http://example.com', ) name='John Doe'

u3 = User(url="ht://example.com")
# OUT:
#  ValidationError: 1 validation error for User
#  url
#    URL scheme not permitted (type=value_error.url.scheme; allowed_schemes={'http', 'https'})
```

If you really need to use `json.dumps`, write a Custom Encoder:

```py
import json


class EnhancedJSONEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, o):
        if isinstance(o, BaseModel):
            return o.dict()
        return super().default(o)


foo = Foo(count=20)
json.dumps([{"foo": foo}], cls=EnhancedJSONEncoder)
# OUT: '[{"foo": {"count": 20, "size": null}}]'
```

Comment: Note that it's different in Pydantic V2. See migration guide: https://docs.pydantic.dev/2.4/migration

Answer (score 3):

[**dataclass-wizard**](https://dataclass-wizard.readthedocs.io) is a modern option that can work for you. It supports complex types such as date and time, most generics from the `typing` module, and also a *nested dataclass* structure.

The "new style" annotations introduced in PEPs [585](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/) and [604](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.asdict) can be ported back to Python 3.7 via a `__future__` import as shown below.

```py
from __future__ import annotations  # This can be removed in Python 3.10
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from dataclass_wizard import JSONWizard


@dataclass
class MyClass(JSONWizard):
    my_str: str | None
    is_active_tuple: tuple[bool, ...]
    list_of_int: list[int] = field(default_factory=list)


string = """
{
  "my_str": 20,
  "ListOfInt": ["1", "2", 3],
  "isActiveTuple": ["true", false, 1]
}
"""

instance = MyClass.from_json(string)
print(repr(instance))
# MyClass(my_str='20', is_active_tuple=(True, False, True), list_of_int=[1, 2, 3])

print(instance.to_json())
# '{"myStr": "20", "isActiveTuple": [true, false, true], "listOfInt": [1, 2, 3]}'

# True
assert instance == MyClass.from_json(instance.to_json())
```

You can install the Dataclass Wizard with `pip`:

```
$ pip install dataclass-wizard
```

---

A bit of background info:

> For serialization, it uses a slightly modified (a bit more efficient) implementation of [`dataclasses.asdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.asdict). When de-serializing JSON to a dataclass instance, the first time it iterates over the dataclass fields and generates a parser for each annotated type, which makes it more efficient when the de-serialization process is run multiple times.

*Disclaimer*: I am the creator (and maintainer) of this library.

Answer (score 2):

Simply use [orjson](https://pypi.org/project/orjson/).

```
import orjson
foo = Foo(x="bar")
orjson.dumps(foo).decode('utf-8')
```

Answer (score 1):

A much simpler answer can be found [on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/9h74no/convert_dict_to_dataclass/e69p8m8/?utm_source=reddit&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) using dictionary unpacking

```sh
>>> from dataclasses import dataclass
>>> @dataclass
... class MyData:
...   prop1: int
...   prop2: str
...   prop3: int
...
>>> d = {'prop1': 5, 'prop2': 'hi', 'prop3': 100}
>>> my_data = MyData(**d)
>>> my_data
MyData(prop1=5, prop2='hi', prop3=100)
```

Comment: This doesn't support nested dataclasses.

Comment: This can introduce bug if the d comes from a json object. We often suppose that adding a field in a payload is not a breaking change, but here, if you add a field to d, it will break with "got an unexpected keyword argument 'prop4'"

Comment: As far as regarding the original question, this is the simplest correct answer.

Comment: @M2014 it doesn't even address the original question, which is how to serialize a dataclass to JSON.

Answer (score 1):

A dataclass providing json formating method

```py
import json
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Foo:
    x: str
   
    def to_json(self):
      return json.dumps(self.__dict__)

Foo("bar").to_json()
>>> '{"x":"bar"}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay so here is what I did when I was in similar situation.

1. Create a custom dictionary factory that converts nested data classes into dictionary.

   def myfactory(data):
   return dict(x for x in data if x[1] is not None)
2. If foo is your @dataclass, then simply provide your dictionary factory to use "myfactory()" method:

   fooDict = asdict(foo, dict_factory=myfactory)
3. Convert fooDict to json

   fooJson = json.dumps(fooDict)

This should work !!