# why does `json.dumps` yield an empty (stringified) dict when parsing dataclass that subclases `dict`

Tags: python, json, dictionary, python-dataclasses

Why does the following

```py
import json
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Foo(dict):
    bar: Dict

example = Foo(bar={'spam': 'eggs'})
json.dumps(example)
```

yield an empty dict in json string form

```
'{}'
```

*Note: I'm aware that this isn't a sensible struct, rather, just interested in the reason behind the result!*

Comment: The REASON is that the `json` module only knows how to convert integers, floats, strings, tuples, lists and dictionaries.  A `dataclass` behaves a lot like a dictionary, but not enough like one.

Comment: The dict that gets serialized by `json.dumps()` is the one the the instance of `Foo` actually is, rather than one that happens to be stored in an attribute of that instance.

Comment: Ah yes! It's because the `dict` is actually truly empty... The attributes and extras added by `dataclass` just ignored. Indeed `dict(example)` gives `{}`...

Comment: A [`TypedDict`](https://peps.python.org/pep-0589/) may be more suited to your purpose.

Comment: "Ah yes! It's because the dict is actually truly empty." - yes, exactly that. The same reason that it would fail the same way, *without* the `dataclass` decorator.

Answer (score -1):

I think you have to use the [dataclasses.asdict()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.asdict) function to convert the dataclass to dict type obj

```
import json
from dataclasses import dataclass
import dataclasses

@dataclass
class Foo(dict):
    bar: dict

example = Foo(bar={'spam': 'eggs'})
print(json.dumps(dataclasses.asdict(example)))
```

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't answer the question. The question is *why* it yields `'{}'`. You answered *"how to correctly parse a dataclass into json?"* which is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51286748/make-the-python-json-encoder-support-pythons-new-dataclasses