# Error converting dict to json in python

Tags: python, json, dictionary

my dict output looks like this 
[image]

What library to use to convert it to json in python?

edit 1:
my code now looks like

```
import boto3
import json
rds_client = boto3.client('rds', 'ap-southeast-1')
db_instance_info = rds_client.describe_db_instances()
with open('result.json', 'w') as db:
    json.dump(db_instance_info, db)
```

and it shows this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "list.py", line 14, in <module>
    json.dump(db_instance_info, db)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 189, in dump
    for chunk in iterable:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 434, in _iterencode
    for chunk in _iterencode_dict(o, _current_indent_level):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 408, in _iterencode_dict
    for chunk in chunks:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 332, in _iterencode_list
    for chunk in chunks:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 408, in _iterencode_dict
    for chunk in chunks:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 442, in _iterencode
    o = _default(o)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 184, in default
    raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
TypeError: datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 6, 9, 7, 33, 472000, tzinfo=tzutc()) is not JSON serializable
```

Comment: what error? show the full traceback

Comment: here ... https://imgur.com/a/Grvdhor

Comment: Please stop using images for text. We cannot copy and paste from an image to try to reproduce the problem. And the error message must be an edit to the question, not a link to another image in a comment!

Comment: The cause (and the way to fix) is explicit in the error message. But I won't answer until you edit the question with the text of the error.

Comment: @SergeBallesta sorry as the error is too big that's why I opted for posting images instead of text. It's edited now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is explicit:

```
TypeError: datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 6, 9, 7, 33, 472000, tzinfo=tzutc()) is not JSON serializable
```

By default the `json` module cannot serialize any of the types from the `datetime` module, and your dictionary contains `..., u'InstanceCreateTime': datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 6, 9, 7, 33, 472000, tzinfo=tzutc())`, and other datetimes later.

The idiomatic way is to define a custom encoder to process the relevant objects. It is enough to override the default method, process the specific objects and pass everything else to the base class method:

```
class DateEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
"""This encoder only use the default string convertion for the types
date, time and datetime of the datetime module"""
    def default(self, o):
        if (isinstance(o, datetime.date)
            or isinstance(o, datetime.datetime)
            or isinstance(o, datetime.time)):
            return str(o)                # specialize here the format...
        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, o)
```

You can then use it to build your json:

```
with open('result.json', 'w') as db:
    json.dump(db_instance_info, db, cls=DateEncoder)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `json` module:

```
import json
jsonarray = json.dumps(the_dict, ensure_ascii=False)
```

The `ensure_ascii` bit is there to avoid any encoding/decoding errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the json library in python

```
import json
x = {'s': True}
r = json.dumps(x)
```

This will give a json string

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12122007/python-json-encoder-to-support-datetime