# How to deserialize the datetime in a json object in python?

Tags: python, json, datetime

My original dictionary is

```
A = {                                                                                                  
    'date': datetime.date(2013, 1, 1),
    'price': 100
}
```

Since `datetime.date` is not serializable, I add a default function to deal with that:

```
B = json.dumps(A, default=lambda obj:obj.isoformat() if hasattr(obj, 'isoformat') else obj)
```

My question is, how can I deserialize the `'date'` field while I use `json.loads` to convert it back to the original dictionary?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
from datetime import datetime

def load_with_datetime(pairs, format='%Y-%m-%d'):
    """Load with dates"""
    d = {}
    for k, v in pairs:
        if isinstance(v, basestring):
            try:
                d[k] = datetime.strptime(v, format).date()
            except ValueError:
                d[k] = v
        else:
            d[k] = v             
    return d

dump = json.dumps(A, default = f)
json.loads(dump, object_pairs_hook=load_with_datetime)

# {u'date': datetime.date(2013, 1, 1), u'price': 100}
```

Comment: as a personal preference, i check for a regex instead of the try/except block.  but i have object_pairs_hooks that handle multiple formats and require that.

Comment: @JonathanVanasco -- Yup, if you have multiple formats, then using a regex could be an alternative, also I would look at the `dateutil` parser...

Answer (score 3):

continue to your example code,

```
C = json.loads(B)
C['date'] = datetime.datetime.strptime(C['date'], '%Y-%m-%d')
print C
# {u'date': datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 1, 0, 0), u'price': 100}
```

Comment: Is it possible to convert it when doing the `json.loads` command? I have not only one date information. Thanks!

Comment: you may refer to @root's answer, or a more complete solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3235787/693110)

Answer (score 0):

Use pickle module

```
    import pickle
    fileop = open("timeformat.txt","wb")
    pickle.dump(A,fileop)
    fileop.close()
    print pickle.load(open("timeformat.txt","rb"))
    print A['Date']


    >>>{'date': datetime.date(2013, 1, 1), 'price': 100}
    >>>2013-01-01
```