# Echoprint local server returns "<type 'exceptions.TypeError'> at /query datetime.datetime(2013, 3, 5, 5, 10, 31) is not JSON serializable"

Tags: python, json

I booted my own echoprint server by following steps provided at echoprint's github page: https://github.com/echonest/echoprint-server

I was able to set it up properly, and ingested some echoprint's data. I was able to see all ingested data using Solr admin page. I'm pretty sure I did not encounter any issue when it comes to ingestion.

But when I tried querying in my browser, my server always returns this: 
**datetime.datetime(2013, 3, 5, 5, 10, 31) is not JSON serializable**

What could be the problem here? I am actually not familiar with python, so I'm having a hard time solving this.

Answer (score 0):

`datetime.datetime(...)` is a python datetime object. It is not in a format JSON can recognized. JSON data types can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#Data_types.2C_syntax_and_example)). To learn how to properly serialize the datetime object, see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2680060/875127).