# how to store and access datetime(s) in a Python object that needs to be converted into JSON?

Tags: python, json, datetime, object

I'm working on my first python script, which creates and updates and object with different datetime entries.

I'm setting up the object like this:

```
# Date conversion
import datetime
import time

# 0:01:00 and 0:00:00 threshold and totalseconds
threshold = time.strptime('00:01:00,000'.split(',')[0],'%H:%M:%S')
tick = datetime.timedelta(hours=threshold.tm_hour,minutes=threshold.tm_min,seconds=threshold.tm_sec).total_seconds()
zero_time = datetime.timedelta(hours=0,minutes=0,seconds=0)
zero_tick = zero_time.total_seconds()
format_date = '%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S'

from datetime import datetime

# Response object
class ResponseObject(object):
    def __init__(self, dict):
      self.__dict__ = dict

# JSON encoding
from json import JSONEncoder
class MyEncoder(JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, o):
      return o.__dict__

# > check for JSON response object
try:
   obj
except NameError:
    obj = ResponseObject({})

...
entry = "14/Nov/2012:09:32:31 +0100"
entry_tz = str.join(' ', entry.split(None)[1:6])
entry_notz = entry.replace(' '+entry_tz,'')
this_time = datetime.strptime(entry_notz, format_date)

# > add machine to object if not there, add init time
if not hasattr(obj, "SOFTINST"):
    #line-breaks for readability
    setattr(obj, "SOFTINST", {  
        "init":this_time,
        "last":this_time,
        "downtime":zero_time,
        "totaltime":"",
        "percentile":100
    })
... 
print this_time
print MyEncoder().encode({"hello":"bar"})
print getattr(obj, "SOFTINST")
```

My last 'print' returns this:

```
{
  'totaltime': datetime.timedelta(0),
  'uptime': '',
  'last': datetime.datetime(2012, 11, 14, 9, 32, 31),
  'init': datetime.datetime(2012, 11, 14, 9, 32, 31),
  'percentile': 100, 
  'downtime': 0
}
```

Which I cannot convert into JSON...

I don't understand why this:

```
print this_time   #2012-11-14 09:32:31
```

but inside the object, it's stored as

```
datetime.datetime(2012, 11, 14, 9, 32, 31)
```

**Question:**
How do I store datetime objects in "string format" and still have them easily accessible (and modifyable) in Python?

Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at the following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/455580/json-datetime-between-python-and-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the isoformat method on the datetime object. (see reference: http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/datetime-datetime.html)