# Using FullCalendar with Django Views

Tags: django, django-views, fullcalendar

I'm trying to implement the FullCalendar on my website, but am a little new to this and not quite sure how to format what I want to do. I have a view which will grab all of an individual user's events. I want to take those events and populate the calendar with them. My issue is that I don't know what to return in the view or how to handle that return value in the JavaScript function. Here's what I have right now:

View:

```
def calEvents(request):

    user = request.user.get_profile()
    eventList = user.eventList
    ownedList = user.ownedEvent

    events = #Part I'm having trouble with

    return HttpResponse(events)
```

The `eventList` and `ownedEvent` keep track of all of a user's events. They have names/dates associated with them. What I don't understand is the format I need to put all that information in to return in my HttpResponse.

My JavaScript function is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {


    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
      eventSources: [
        {
            url: '/calEvents/',
            editable: false,
        }
      ]
    });

});
```

I'm telling it to go to the Django view, but am lost after that. Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done this by building a list of dictionaries in my Django view, setting at minimum the required fields of 'title' and the start time, then using `simplejson.dumps` with `cls=DjangoJSONEncoder` to return json.

```
from django.core.serializers.json import DjangoJSONEncoder

def calEvents(request):
    # as above, then:
    events = []
    for event in eventList:
        events.append({'title': event.name, 'start': event.start})
    # something similar for owned events, maybe with a different className if you like
    return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(events, cls=DjangoJSONEncoder), mimetype='application/json')
```

You may also with to limit the events you return based on the starting and ending times provided by the get request:

```
def calEvents(request):
    user = request.user.get_profile()
    start_timestamp = request.GET.get('start')
    end_timestamp = request.GET.get('end')
    start_datetime = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(float(start_timestamp))
    end_datetime = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(float(end_timestamp))
    eventList = user.eventList.filter(start_time__lte=end_datetime, end_time__gte=start_datetime)
```

I am neglecting error handling for the timestamp conversion - fullcalendar will give you appropriate values, but it would be best to allow for the possibility of bad input.  And I am making assumptions about the structure of your event models.

Comment: This resulted in `TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'namedtuple_as_object'`. After googling it, I saw it mentioned some backwards compatibility issues when used in Django. Is there a workaround?

Comment: Which version of Django are you on?

Comment: Got it working using just json.dumps without the encoder. Thanks!

Comment: Interesting - on my older version the default encoder couldn't handle `datetime`s, which was the motivation for using the Django specific one.  The standard Python library's docs don't report it handling `datetime`s by default, so I am pleasantly surprised that it works without adding a custom encoder of some sort.

Comment: Oh, I will probably end up having to find one of those. At the moment, I just manually entered "2013-07-15". My goal here was just to get something to show up. I think I can figure out the kinks after that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/455580/json-datetime-between-python-and-javascript like it has multiple good answers for when you do need to add it in.