# how to create a ndb.DateTimeProperty property from javascript

Tags: python, google-app-engine, endpoints-proto-datastore

I use Google app engine cloud endpoint. One class I have including a DateTimeProperty property to be set by end user.

```
class Schedule(EndpointsModel):
  id = ndb.StringProperty()
  scheduleTime = ndb.DateTimeProperty()
  created = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now=True)
```

and I try to call the endpoint from the javascript

```
gapi.client.myendpoints.schedules.insert({
    'id': 11121,
    'scheduleTime ': '12/22/14 19:00'
    }).execute()
```

But no matter what I tried (such as '12/22/14 19:00',1411130222) 
the server always responses:
    TypeError: Could not deserialize timestamp: 09/20/14 11:11am.

Does anyone know if there is a way to create a ndb.DateTimeProperty property from javascript? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

Figure it out.
use the EndpointsDateTimeProperty to add the parse format

```
myDate= EndpointsDateTimeProperty(string_format='%m/%d/%y %H:%M')
```

Here is more detailed discussion. 
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/endpoints-proto-datastore/issues/83

Answer (score 0):

You may find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6130825/3852106) answer useful. You'll have to implement a handler that will receive a JSON serialized datetime object, deserealize it to a datetime object and store it in the datastore.