# Timezone aware DateTime fields in django forms

Tags: django, django-forms, timezone, django-timezone

In short, I'm trying to show the user a DateTime field initialized with a timezone aware datetime object, allow them to edit it and post it back. Without doing anything special I get a warning about a non-timezone aware datetime being returned to the form's DateTime field.

```
/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py:1474: RuntimeWarning:
    DateTimeField MyModel.datetimefield received a naive datetime (2015-09-09 15:55:00)
    while time zone support is active.
```

I started by reading [the django time zones docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/timezones/). I installed pytz (`pip install pytz`) and made sure [`USE_TZ = True`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#use-tz) was set.

I'm using [django-easy-timezones](https://github.com/Miserlou/django-easy-timezones), which sets the "current" timezone based on the requester's IP with a call to [`timezone.activate()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/#selecting-the-current-time-zone). As I understand it, the setting [`TIME_ZONE`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#time-zone) would otherwise be used as the default. I'm also also using [`django-bootstrap3-datetimepicker`](https://github.com/nkunihiko/django-bootstrap3-datetimepicker) for a nice widget in my form.

The timezone doesn't appear to be sent with the initial form data. Instead, the "current" timezone is used to create and send a naive local datetime. From [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/timezones/#time-zone-aware-input-in-forms) I gather the `clean_[field]` method is meant to assume what comes back in the POST is also in the "current" timezone. Is this done automatically or am I meant to make the data timezone aware myself? If so, why might I be getting the warning?

Would it make more sense to simply send the timezone back and forth, always having a timezone aware datetime? If so, getting the datetime to javascript is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455580/json-datetime-between-python-and-javascript), but I haven't found a nice way of returning it to the DateTime field format wise (especially with the widget not using a format with a timezone).

Comment: I have a very similar, almost identical tech setup and was wondering the same :)