# Persist datetime values for use with gviz api

Tags: python, json, google-visualization

I have an python application that collects data from an MQTT broker and presents it to a website via the gviz python API:

```
DESCRIPTION= [      \
              ('Zeit', 'datetime'),     \
              ('Temperatur', 'number'),  \
              ('Feuchtigkeit', 'number'),\
              ('Batterie', 'number')    \
              ]

def sendAnswer(conn):
#protect against the data supplier
    Mutex.acquire()
    Trans = deepcopy(DatArr)
    Mutex.release()
#create and populate the DataTable    
    data_table = gviz_api.DataTable(DESCRIPTION)
    data_table.LoadData(Trans)
    Answer = data_table.ToJSon()
#send ti to the webserver
    lng = len(Answer)
    try:
        conn.sendall(bytes("L{:06d};".format(lng),"UTF-8"))
        conn.sendall(bytes(Answer,"UTF-8"))
    except BaseException:
        # if anything goes wrong, try again next time
        pass

def on_message(client, userdata, message):
    global Last, DatArr
#get the data from the broker
    cur = json.loads(str(message.payload, encoding='utf-8'))
    if cur == Last and len(DatArr)>2 : return
    now = datetime.now()
# protect against the webserver
    Mutex.acquire()
#add the data
    DatArr.append([now, cur["temp"], cur["hum"], cur["bat"]])
#cleanup old values
    Last = cur
    for i in range(len(DatArr)):
        if now - DatArr[0][0] > timedelta(days=1): 
            DatArr.pop(0) 
        else:
            break
    Mutex.release()
```

This works, but instead of keeping the data in the python variable I want to persist it in a file (preferrably JSON). But I cannot JSON.dump() a datetime variable and I cannot .LoadData() a string into a  gviz DataTable. The python gviz also lacks an "addRow()". Any suggestions?

Much thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not familiar with the python gviz API, but when using the google charts data table as json, you can use the [date string representation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/datesandtimes#dates-and-times-using-the-date-string-representation) which does not require the `new` operator -- not sure if this helps...

Comment: Thanks, but you are referring to a page that deals with Java Script:
"The date and datetime DataTable column data types utilize the built-in JavaScript Date class."
The question was about a  python implementation. My problem is, that I can dump the datetime as string (using the str() operator) but then the type information is lost and gviz refuses to load the data.
Thanks anyway :-)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answers to this question: [JSON datetime between Python and JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455580/json-datetime-between-python-and-javascript?rq=1)
I found a solution and implemented it in a python module:

```
import json
import datetime

class DateTimeJSONEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, datetime.datetime):
            return dict(nested_datetime=obj.isoformat())
        else:
            return super(DateTimeJSONEncoder, self).default(obj)

def datetime_decoder(d):
    if len(d) == 1 and 'nested_datetime' in d: 
        return datetime.datetime.strptime(d['nested_datetime'], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')
    result = {}
    for prop in d:
        if isinstance(d[prop], dict):
            result[prop] = datetime_decoder(d[prop])
        else:
            result[prop] = d[prop]
    return result
```

The class and the function go as named parameters into the json.dump and json.load functions like this:

```
 DatArr = json.load(DatFile, object_hook=djson.datetime_decoder)
```

and

```
json.dump(DatArr, DatFile, cls=djson.DateTimeJSONEncoder)
```

This persists the formerly global variable DatArr in the json file DatFile.
Thanks to all the posters to the above question for providing the information.